# Windows 10 using onboard intel and not Radeon card

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, amd-radeon

When I first bought this PC I had to jump through some hoops (which I've since forgotten) in order for it to use my AMD Radeon RX 480 card rather than the Intel HD graphics 630 on board GPU. All was well.
Windows 10 has just completed an update - the features update - and after a reboot a notification about a driver being removed was displayed. It was more like a balloon tip and had faded away before I could read it. Now a lot of my graphical "stuff" is dim. The desktop wallpaper, my favourite game looks like it's midnight!

I went to AMD settings and it said it could not display the settings as no monitor was connected to the monitor. I used AMD clean intsall utility which cleanses the PC of all previous drivers and utilities. I then ran AMD reLive which adds the latest drivers and software back. I can now run Radeon settings.
Everything still seems dim and I can't switch to Radeon in my game settings (intel is the only option).

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you physically plug a monitor in to the Intel video? You can’t “use” one graphic card and be plugged in to a different one, at least not in this example. You are using whatever video card you are plugged in to.

Comment: Try updating the driver using Windows. W10 breaks it, but sometimes W10 also correctly fixes it.

Comment: have you checked if there is anything wrong with the cabling? Make sure you plug your monitor into the graphics card **not** the display connector of the mainboard. Try a different cable, especially the old VGA cable are prone to pins breaking off.

Comment: As Overmind mentioned, you should update your GPU drivers. Windows 10 has always broken my AMD drivers when it upgraded to a new major version (or build).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the GPU to be doing its job all the time. I'd choose "High Performance" battery plan when it's plugged and/or on battery.

Besides, following AMD switch graphics guide to force your game use the AMD Radeon graphics, note the part of Assigning Applications to GPUs.

https://community.amd.com/docs/DOC-1581